# How can I run a JavaScript function every time an HTML element is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

I need to run a script every time a table is resized (whenever the user resizes the browser window). Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('resized');
}

window.onresize = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.onresize = function(){alert('test');}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jquery,

$(window).resize(function() {

alert("test now");

});