# How get 2 divs same height using scroll-y and flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want this scrollable div to be the same height like the div next to it.
This is what I got so far:

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <div>
       The height must be determined by this div.
    </div>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll">
       This div has a lot of content.
       The height must follow the div next to me.
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the right div is always as big as its content.
Both divs have dynamic content, so I don't know the exact height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First read her the diff between :
`overflow-y: scroll` to `auto` (In your case its better to use auto). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

One more pre-step `align-items: flex-start;` (Like this the height of the col will not match).

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

[How to disable equal height columns in Flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034660/how-to-disable-equal-height-columns-in-flexbox)

### "real" solution (for all cases) - only by Javascript

```js
/* set max-height by code */
var colHeight = document.getElementById("child_1").getBoundingClientRect().height;
console.log(colHeight);
document.getElementById("child_2").style.maxHeight = colHeight+"px";
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

#child_1{
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
#child_2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<main class='parent'>
  <div id="child_1">
    <p>
      Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases  - Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases 
    </p>
    <p>
      Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases  - Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="child_2">
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

### Extra step (Set max-height if window resize)

When you set `max-height` by code - you should run this every time the browser resize (Safier approach for responsive sites)
:
[How can I run a JavaScript function every time an HTML element is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733533/how-can-i-run-a-javascript-function-every-time-an-html-element-is-resized)

```js
function resize() {
/* set max-height by code */
var colHeight = document.getElementById("child_1").getBoundingClientRect().height;
console.log(colHeight);
document.getElementById("child_2").style.maxHeight = colHeight+"px";
console.log('resized');
}

resize();
window.onresize = resize;
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#child_1{
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
#child_2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 2px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<main class='parent'>
  <div id="child_1">
    <p>
      Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases  - Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases 
    </p>
    <p>
      Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases  - Fit to content in all cases - Fit to content in all cases 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="child_2">
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Extra reading:

- **getBoundingClientRect:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getboundingclientrect.asp
- **onresize:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize

### Disable on mobile:

This `max-height` trick is not so useful on small screens. One solution (If window width higher than X run function).

```
function resize() {
  /* set max-height by code */
  if (window.innerWidth > 960) {
    var colHeight = document.getElementById("child_1").getBoundingClientRect().height;
    console.log("window width" + window.innerWidth +"px");
    document.getElementById("child_2").style.maxHeight = colHeight+"px";
  }
}

resize();
window.onresize = resize;
```

[Do something if screen width is less than 960 px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px)

---

### Why CSS is not enough?

Keep in mind "max-height" without any set of overflow = "unresponsive" site.

**Option 1 - left col is shorter than right col:**

Set right col height to: `max-height: 100px;`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

#child_1{
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
#child_2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<main class='parent'>
  <div id="child_1">
    <p>
      Very short content
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="child_2">
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

**Option 2 - left col is longer than right col:**

In this case, one option is to set `max-height` for the parent (Very Very unresponsive approach - because you should declare overflow for both cols) + Very weird UI:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
}

#child_1{
  border: 3px solid orange;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#child_2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<main class='parent'>
  <div id="child_1">
    <p>
      Tall div
    </p>
    <p>
      Tall div
    </p>
    <p>
      Tall div
    </p>
    <p>
      Tall div
    </p>
    <p>
      Tall div
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="child_2">
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
    <p>
      This div has a lot of content.
      The height must follow the div next to me.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the exact height because the content of both divs are dynamic which makes this problem very difficult

Comment: I added JS a very simple solution (2-3 lines of code).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to add a `height` or `max-height` to the parent element. That way both children have the same height at any width.

```
// HTML
<div id='container' class='parent'>
    <div id='content' class='child'>
       The height must be determined by this div.
    </div>
    <div class='child'>
       This div has a lot of content.
       The height must follow the div next to me.
    </div>
</div>
```

```
// CSS
.parent {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 70px; // remove if using JavaScript
}

.child {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Alternatively you could use JavaScript to determine the current height of your first child element and make that the height of the parent element.

ADDED:

```
// JS
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

const updateContainer = () => {
  let contentHeight = content.clientHeight + 'px';

  container.style.height = contentHeight;
}

updateContainer();
```

This is just an example. You would need to use an event listener to trigger the function.

Comment: also if OP used different classes for the children, a css variable for height could be used (just another option)..

Comment: Unfortunately the content in the left div is dynamic. So I don't know the exact height...

Comment: I've added an example how to do dynamic changes.